# What is Enable-Mailbox powershell doing 'under the covers'? What does RUS handle?

Tags: exchange, powershell

I have a system with a million ID's or so, and we will be managing new accounts in Active Directory.  For a variety of reasons, using PowerShell to call Enable-MailUser (just need them in the GAL, not to give them mail boxes).

We know from this [MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275636) that there are a number of attributes to be twiddled.  But there are some if left alone that the RUS service (Recipient Update Service) will update.

We are now at a point, where the AD admins want to know what really happens under the covers in the Enable-MailUser commandlet.

I.e. Is it the PS or RUS that sets

- LegacyExchangeDN
- proxyAddresses values for X400
- textEncodedORAddress

Then the same questions in the case of a user rename.

Actually, what do you do in Exchange if the user is renamed in AD?  That is the CN component changes or the sAMAccountName changes.  Which is a rename event to Exchange's world view?  Do you need to recall Enable-MailUser to update the user after the data changes?

I did not yet mention which Exchange version, and that is somewhat on purpose.  If the answer differs by Exchange version, then that would be critical to note!

Currently working with Exchange 2007 but they intend to move to 2010 very soon now as well.

They are convinced there is very much magic in the Enable-MailUser function, and are afraid of its voodoo power.  I need to peel back the covers so that we can manage what needs to be managed without superstitious fears.

Comment: Just so you know, [RUS is no more](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/10/02/429053.aspx) since Exchange 2007.

Comment: @Ben: That would be very useful information to know!  How does Exchange 2010 do it then?  What is the expected approach to handle what RUS did in 2007, when it is gone in 2010?

Comment: There's no RUS in Exchange 2007.

Comment: sorry if I didn't make my comment clear (it's getting late here :P). Exchange 2003 was the last version to include the RUS - in Exchange 2007 and later versions, the cmdlets do *all* the heavy lifting.

Comment: Good riddance, RUS. You were a non-deterministic pain in the ass.

Answer (score 4):

There's no RUS in Exchange Server 2007 or 2010. The Enable-MailUser cmdlet adds the appropriate attributes to the user object so yes, the cmdlet is directly accessing the user object attributes in AD. Make note that Enable-Mailbox cmdlet (in your title) will mailbox enable a user and create a mailbox for the user while the Enable-MailUser cmdlet (in your question) will only mail enable a user (no mailbox).

Comment: So the Exchange Admins tell me there is some process running every 12 hours that looks at the various objects that are almost right and touches them up to be ready for Exchange.  What is that service called in 2007 now, if not RUS?

Comment: I would like to see a list of the attributes that the cmdlet's add, since we would like to do them in our Identity Management solution instead of using PowerShell.